# Is it possible to call Javascript's onsubmit event programmatically on a form?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

In Ruby on Rails, I'm attempting to update the `innerHTML` of a div tag using the `form_remote_tag` helper.  This update happens whenever an associated select tag receives an onchange event.  The problem is, `<select onchange="this.form.submit();">`; doesn't work.  Nor does `document.forms[0].submit()`.  The only way to get the onsubmit code generated in the form_remote_tag to execute is to create a hidden submit button, and invoke the click method on the button from the select tag.  Here's a working ERb partial example.

```
<% form_remote_tag :url => product_path, :update => 'content', :method => 'get' do -%>
  <% content_tag :div, :id => 'content' do -%>
    <%= select_tag :update, options_for_select([["foo", 1], ["bar", 2]]), :onchange => "this.form.commit.click" %>
    <%= submit_tag 'submit_button', :style => "display: none" %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

What I want to do is something like this, but it doesn't work.

```
<% form_remote_tag :url => product_path, :update => 'content', :method => 'get' do -%>
  <% content_tag :div, :id => 'content' do -%>
    # the following line does not work
    <%= select_tag :update, options_for_select([["foo", 1], ["bar", 2]]), :onchange => "this.form.onsubmit()" %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

So, is there any way to remove the invisible submit button for this use case?

There seems to be some confusion.  So, let me explain.  The basic problem is that `submit()` doesn't call the `onsubmit()` code rendered into the form.

The actual HTML form that Rails renders from this ERb looks like this:

```
<form action="/products/1" method="post" onsubmit="new Ajax.Updater('content', '/products/1', {asynchronous:true, evalScripts:true, method:'get', parameters:Form.serialize(this)}); return false;">
  <div style="margin:0;padding:0">
    <input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="4eacf78eb87e9262a0b631a8a6e417e9a5957cab" />
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    <select id="update" name="update" onchange="this.form.commit.click">
      <option value="1">foo</option>
      <option value="2">bar</option>
    </select>
    <input name="commit" style="display: none" type="submit" value="submit_button" />
  </div>
</form>
```

I want to axe the invisible submit button, but using a straight form.submit appears to not work.  So, I need some way to call the form's onsubmit event code.

Update: Orion Edwards solution would work if there wasn't a `return(false);` generated by Rails.  I'm not sure which is worse though, sending a phantom click to an invisible submit button or calling eval on the `getAttribute('onsubmit')` call after removing the return call with a javascript string replacement!

Answer (score -3, accepted):

If you didn't actually want to submit the form, but just invoke whatever code happened to be in the onsubmit, you could possibly do this: (untested)

```
var code = document.getElementById('formId').getAttribute('onsubmit');
eval(code);
```

Comment: This works in theory, but I still use my original code in production just to avoid having to use an eval.

Answer (score 5):

I realize this question is kind of old, but what the heck are you doing eval for?

```
document.getElementById('formId').onsubmit();
document.getElementById('formId').submit();
```

or

```
document.formName.onsubmit();
document.formName.submit();
```

When the DOM of a document is loaded, the events are not strings any more, they are functions.

```
alert(typeof document.formName.onsubmit); // function
```

So there's no reason to convert a function to a string just so you can eval it.

Answer (score 3):

give your form an `id`.

then

```
document.getElementById('formid').submit();
```

If you are loading Javascript into a `div` via `innerHTML`, it won't run...just FYI.

Answer (score 2):

If you have to use Rail's built-in Javascript generation, I would use Orion's solution, but with one small alteration to compensate for the return code.

```
eval ('(function(){' + code + '})()');
```

However, in my opinion you'd have an easier time in the long run by separating out the Javascript code into an external file or separate callable functions.

Answer (score 1):

Don't.

You have a solution.

Stop, move on to the next function point.

I know, it is not pretty, but there are bigger problems.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you have an answer yet or not, but in the `onclick` function of the select, call `onsubmit` instead of `submit`.

Answer (score -1):

In theory, something like `eval ('function(){' + code + '}()');` could work (that syntax fails though).  Even if that did work, it would still be sort of ghetto to be calling an eval through a select `onchange`.  Another solution would be to somehow get Rails to inject the `onsubmit` code into the `onchange` field of the select tag, but I'm not sure if there's a way to do that.  ActionView has link_to_remote, but there's no obvious helper to generate the same code in the `onchange` field.