# How do I programmatically force an onchange event on an input?

Tags: javascript

How do I programmatically force an onchange event on an input?

I've tried something like this:

```
var code = ele.getAttribute('onchange');
eval(code);
```

But my end goal is to fire any listener functions, and that doesn't seem to work.  Neither does just updating the 'value' attribute.

Answer (score 277, accepted):

Create an `Event` object and pass it to the `dispatchEvent` method of the element:

```
var element = document.getElementById('just_an_example');
var event = new Event('change');
element.dispatchEvent(event);
```

This will trigger event listeners regardless of whether they were registered by calling the `addEventListener` method or by setting the `onchange` property of the element.

---

By default, events created and dispatched like this don't propagate (bubble) up the DOM tree like events normally do.

If you want the event to bubble, you need to pass a second argument to the `Event` constructor:

```
var event = new Event('change', { bubbles: true });
```

---

Information about browser compability:

- [dispatchEvent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent#Browser_Compatibility)
- [Event()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/Event#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: Yes, the [MDN Creating and triggering events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events) is a good resource!

Comment: This is how to do it properly, natively. Supported in all browsers now: http://caniuse.com/#feat=dispatchevent

Comment: Im trying to do the equivalent on IE11 but it's not working when trying to change a reactjs input field.

`var evt = document.createEvent('CustomEvent');
    evt.initCustomEvent('input', true, false, { });
    elem.dispatchEvent(evt);`

Comment: Why is everyone saying this is the best answer? According to the linked Event doc, even the current version of IE *still* doesn't support this.

Comment: How can i pass parameters to the change event ?

Comment: `{ bubbles: true }` this was the fix for my issue. Thanks

Answer (score 108):

In jQuery I mostly use:

```
$("#element").trigger("change");
```

Comment: tihs helped me! I was setting the value of a checkbox (checked or not) using code and the event was not firing in IE at all no matter what i did. I tried blur() focus() and a few other things. after i set the value i called trigger and i added a click event to call trigger as well. It causes multiple fires but it doesnt matter to me. 

In IE I add checkboxes through code and you have to click on them twice before the change event fires. Thanks for this tip.

Comment: As an update, $("#element").change(); does the same thing since jquery 1.0.

Comment: Note that this does NOT trigger a native onchange. It will only fire on all the onchange listeners that were bound through jQuery!

Answer (score 64):

ugh don't use eval for *anything*.  Well, there are certain things, but they're extremely rare.
Rather, you would do this:

```
document.getElementById("test").onchange()
```

Look here for more options:
http://jehiah.cz/archive/firing-javascript-events-properly

Comment: eval for objectifying JSON ;)

Comment: Agreed about eval - I pulled that code from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33860/is-it-possible-to-call-javascripts-onsubmit-event-programatically-on-a-form as an example of something I don't want.

Comment: This doesn't appear to work in IE7. Exception of "object doesn't support this property or method" - do you see that too?

Comment: json2.js for objectifying JSON!  JSON.parse is already available on modern browsers

Comment: eval for objectifying JSON is a really bad idea, and can lead to serious security vulnerabilities. ALWAYS use JSON.parse for that sort of thing.

Comment: This technique *only* works if the change handler was attached by setting "onchange". It does not generate a 'real' event that triggers w3c or microsoft event handlers. See the link for more details.

Comment: I think this answer is outdated now, [Miscreant's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36648958/204205) using `new Event(...)` and `dispatchEvent` is the right solution nowadays, it seems.

Comment: This is not how it should be done because it will NOT trigger a general, native, onchange event. Please use the dispatchEvent(new Event('change')) function. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events it is supported in all browsers these days.

Comment: Not working...
use instead jQuery: `$("#element").trigger("change");` OR 
javaScript: `var event = new Event('change');
element.dispatchEvent(event);`

Comment: @AmitShah jQuery $('#element').trigger('change'); worked perfectly for me.  Thank you.

Comment: **This answer is obsoleted**; the code above will not work if you used `Element.addEventListener` to handle events. To achieve it in a modern way, see @Miscreant's answer.

Answer (score 24):

For some reason ele.onchange() is throwing a "method not found" expception for me in IE on my page, so I ended up using this function from the link [Kolten](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13959/kolten) provided and calling fireEvent(ele, 'change'), which worked:

```
function fireEvent(element,event){
    if (document.createEventObject){
        // dispatch for IE
        var evt = document.createEventObject();
        return element.fireEvent('on'+event,evt)
    }
    else{
        // dispatch for firefox + others
        var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
        evt.initEvent(event, true, true ); // event type,bubbling,cancelable
        return !element.dispatchEvent(evt);
    }
}
```

I did however, create a test page that confirmed calling should onchange() work:

```
<input id="test1" name="test1" value="Hello" onchange="alert(this.value);"/>
<input type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('test1').onchange();" value="Say Hello"/>
```

Edit: The reason ele.onchange() didn't work was because I hadn't actually declared anything for the onchange event.  But the fireEvent still works.

Comment: I like this method of browser detection (by object detection) better than the example I provided.

Comment: This do not work anymore for Firefox 23 : "element.dispatchEvent is not a function"

Comment: Hi fellow Googlers. It's 2016! Nowadays we write code like `element.dispatchEvent(new Event('change', true, true))` instead of all that arcane and mostly deprecated `createEvent` and `initEvent` stuff.

Answer (score 4):

This is the most correct answer for IE and Chrome::

```js
var element = document.getElementById('xxxx');
var evt = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
evt.initEvent('change', false, true);
element.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

Answer (score 2):

Taken from the bottom of [QUnit](http://dev.jquery.com/view/trunk/qunit/testrunner.js)

```
function triggerEvent( elem, type, event ) {
    if ( $.browser.mozilla || $.browser.opera ) {
        event = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
        event.initMouseEvent(type, true, true, elem.ownerDocument.defaultView,
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
        elem.dispatchEvent( event );
    } else if ( $.browser.msie ) {
        elem.fireEvent("on"+type);
    }
}
```

You can, of course, replace the $.browser stuff to your own browser detection methods to make it jQuery independent.

To use this function:

```
var event;
triggerEvent(ele, "change", event);
```

This will basically fire the real DOM event as if something had actually changed.

Answer (score 1):

If you add all your events with this snippet  of code:

```
//put this somewhere in your JavaScript:
HTMLElement.prototype.addEvent = function(event, callback){
  if(!this.events)this.events = {};
  if(!this.events[event]){
    this.events[event] = [];
    var element = this;
    this['on'+event] = function(e){
      var events = element.events[event];
      for(var i=0;i<events.length;i++){
        events[i](e||event);
      }
    }
  }
  this.events[event].push(callback);
}
//use like this:
element.addEvent('change', function(e){...});
```

then you can just use `element.on<EVENTNAME>()` where `<EVENTNAME>` is the name of your event, and that will call all events with `<EVENTNAME>`

Answer (score -1):

The `change` event in an `input` element is triggered directly **only by the user**. To trigger the change event **programmatically** we need to `dispatch` the change event.

The question is *Where* and *How*?

**"Where"** we want the change event to be triggered exactly at *the moment after* a bunch of codes is executed, and **"How"** is in the form of the following syntax:

```
const myInput = document.getElementById("myInputId");

function myFunc() {
  //some codes
  myInput.dispatchEvent(new Event("change"));
}
```

In this way, we created the change event programmatically by using the `Event` constructor and dispatched it by the `dispatchEvent()` method. So whenever `myFunc()` method is invoked, after the `//some codes` are executed, our **synthetic change event** is immediately triggered on the desired input element.‍

**Important result:** Here, the `change` event is triggered by executing the `//some codes` in `myFunc()` instead of changing the input `value` by the user (default mode).

Answer (score -5):

if you're using jQuery you would have:

```
$('#elementId').change(function() { alert('Do Stuff'); });
```

or MS AJAX:

```
$addHandler($get('elementId'), 'change', function(){ alert('Do Stuff'); });
```

Or in the raw HTML of the element:

```
<input type="text" onchange="alert('Do Stuff');" id="myElement" />
```

After re-reading the question I think I miss-read what was to be done. I've never found a way to update a DOM element in a manner which will force a change event, what you're best doing is having a separate event handler method, like this:

```
$addHandler($get('elementId'), 'change', elementChanged);
function elementChanged(){
  alert('Do Stuff!');
}
function editElement(){
  var el = $get('elementId');
  el.value = 'something new';
  elementChanged();
}
```

Since you're already writing a JavaScript method which will do the changing it's only 1 additional line to call.

Or, if you *are* using the Microsoft AJAX framework you can access all the event handlers via:

```
$get('elementId')._events
```

It'd allow you to do some reflection-style workings to find the right event handler(s) to fire.

Comment: I believe he wants to fire the actual event, not run a function when the event is fired... i _think_. lol

Answer (score -8):

Using JQuery you can do the following:

```
// for the element which uses ID
$("#id").trigger("change");

// for the element which uses class name
$(".class_name").trigger("change");
```

Comment: undefined is not a function.

Answer (score -8):

For triggering any event in Javascript.

```
 document.getElementById("yourid").addEventListener("change", function({
    //your code here
})
```

Comment: this is listening for events, not triggering them.