# Does the onchange event propagate?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm using event delegation to listen for events lower in the DOM, but it's not working for an onchange event on a select box.  Does the onchange event propagate or bubble up the DOM?

Googling has failed in finding a conclusive answer.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

[According to specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-htmlevents-h3), `change`, `submit`, `reset` should bubble and `focus` and `blur` should not bubble.

This behavior is implemented properly in all web browsers except IE < 9, that is, `change`, `submit`, `reset` do bubble properly in IE >= 9.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/4722246/227299 for a jQuery workaround on old IE versions

- http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/change.html
- http://quirksmode.org/dom/events/submit.html

Comment: I don't understand the first sentence of this answer, if it's true, as you say, that change is spec'd as bubbling, and it's implemented properly in most browsers. Is that a mistake?

Comment: @Sergey, Can you clarify your answer? In the first sentence you say it doesn't bubble, in the second sentence you say it does... ? Why did this answer get so many upvotes?

Comment: @mediafreakch Because even though it was confusing, it had the right information. I've updated the answer to be clearer and added references

Comment: Bubbling change event fires only after focus out/in.

Comment: In case anyone else misreads this at first as I did (and apparently @mediafreakch too): "change", "submit", and "reset" DO bubble and "focus" and "blur" DO NOT bubble -- at least in spec-compliant browsers.

Comment: Since this answer is still a top result of a certain search engine, you might want to have a look at [this other question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136617/how-do-i-programmatically-force-an-onchange-event-on-an-input), which I found more helpful, given that jQuery and IE may not be your main concern in 2024 and assuming that you're looking for a way to force the event propagation up to the root.

Answer (score 23):

In jQuery 1.4+ the change event bubbles in all browsers, including IE.

```
$('div.field_container').change(function() {
   // code here runs in all browers, including IE.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't dealt with this for quite a while, but last time I did, I remember that Firefox recognized the event on the `<SELECT>` element, while IE6 recognized only events on the `<OPTION>` tags. As far as I remember.

IE7 was not out at that time.

So if this is the case, it makes even more sense to not write the event handler inline and apply it on DOM ready instead, lest you are going to have a lot of polluted, repetitive code.

Comment: No IE has a bug in that it doesn't register events on the <option> elements at all (IE6, IE7, IE8) see bug report and test page here:
http://webbugtrack.blogspot.com/2007/11/bug-280-lack-of-events-for-options.html

Answer (score -3):

Not sure if I get the question, but if you mean this, then NO.

```
<div id="foo">
  <select onchange="alert('hi');">
    <option>Hello</option>
    <option>World</option>
  </select>
</foo>
```

Where the div id="foo" would have an onchange event... bubbling up from the select list?

---

on a related note, just an FYI you can't attach an event to the options within the select list in IE (well, you can but it won't fire)