# How to automatically sum input value boxes in an HTML table that share the same name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, velocity

I have an HTML table with columns of input boxes, and would like the sum of the values in the boxes to be displayed automatically (i.e. without clicking a sum button and updates as the values in the boxes are changed). The number of rows in the table varies as it is dynamically created through velocity.  Below is an example HTML table, I want the sum of the values in the capacity row to be displayed. I am not really sure where to start, I have tried numerous JavaScript code and have been unable to get anything to correctly work.

```
 <table border = "1" id = "table">
  <TR>
        <TH>Resource</TH> 
        <TH>Vacation</TH>
        <TH>Allocation</TH>
        <TH>Holidays</TH> 
        <TH>Capacity</TH>
        <TH>Remainder</TH>
    </TR>

  #foreach($user in $userList)
  <tr>
  <td>$user.resource</td>

        <td><input type=text name="vacation" size="6" maxlength="10"></td>
        <td><input type=text name="alloc" size="6" maxlength="10"></td>
        <td><input type=text name="holidays" size="6" maxlength="10"></td>
        <td><input type=text name="capacity" size="6" maxlength="10"></td>
        <td><input type=text name="remainder" size="6" maxlength="10"></td>
    </tr>
  #end 
  <tr>
  <td>Total:</td>
  <td></td><td></td><td></td>
  <td class= "capsum"><input type="text" name="captotal" size="6" maxlength="10"></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="remtotal" size="6" maxlength="10"></td>

  </tr>

  </table>
```

There will be multiple rows in the table, and each input box in the capacity column shares the same name. So the sum of the Capacity column should be displayed in the "capsum" input box, and should be calculated automatically and update as the values in the input boxes are changed.

Comment: Look at using [`.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) to loop through the rows. You can then extract each number and add it to a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
$('table#table input[name=capacity]').change(function()
{
 var sum = 0;

 $('table#table input[name=capacity]').each(function()
 {
  sum += parseInt($(this).val());
 });

 $('input[name=captotal]').val(sum);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/H7DSX/10/

Comment: You're making the assumption that he's using jQuery or would know to use jQuery. You need to pad that answer a bit.

Comment: @MikeFulton The question is tagged with jQuery.

Comment: Oh, so it is. Sorry, I missed that.

Comment: I have jQuery but really do not know how to use it

Answer (score 0):

Hook on the [`change` event](http://api.jquery.com/change/), best at [table level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265074/does-the-onchange-event-propagate). Then sum up all values:

```
var updatefns = {};
jQuery.each(["vacation", "alloc" ,"holidays", "capacity", "remainder"], function(i, name) {
     // cache all the elements
     var head = $("#table tr:first th:nth-child("+i+")"); // kind of selector
     var inputs = $("#table input[name=\""+name+"\"]");
     updatefns[name] = function() {
         var sum = 0;
         inputs.each(function(){
             sum+=parseInt(this.value) || 0;
         });
         // set new text:
         head.text(name.charAt(0).toUppercase+name.substr(1)+": "+sum);
     };
});
$("#table").change(function(e){
     var t, n;
     if ((t = e.target) && (n = t.name) && n in updatefns)
         updatefns[n]();
});
```

You might use a better selector for the head cells to-be-updated, maybe give them a respective attribute to select them. And of course you are free to change the way how the new text is set.

Answer (score -1):

You need to assign a function to be processed for the onChange JavaScript event for the form fields that need to be summed.

This function would then simply read out the values of each of the fields, calculate the sum, and then store it back where it needs to go.

Comment: can you go into more detail on how to do this?

Answer (score -1):

If you have jQuery try:

```
<table onchange="reloadSum()"></table>

var reloadSum = function() {
    var sums = $('.toBeSummed'); // this will need to be the class of the things you want to sum
    var sum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < sums.length; i++) {
        sum += parseFloat(sums[i].value);// or maybe parseFloat(sums[i].innerHTML)
    }
    $('#capsum').text(sum);
}
```

If you don't have jQuery get jQuery and then do this.