# Onclick on a Div

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

Is there a event in HTML, through which, I can execute a function wherever there is any change/click in any element/member of a `<div>`? For example in the code below, I want to execute a function or some lines of code whenever there is any change within any elements of the div "customer". Will a normal onclick work? Any ideas?

```
<div id="customer">
<h3>Customer Information</h3>
<form id="customerinfo" name="customerinfo" style="font-size:14px">
   First Name:&nbsp;<input name="first_name" size="15" type="text" value="Parul">                                                                               
   &nbsp;Last Name:&nbsp;<input name="last_name" size="15" type="text" value="Kashyap"><br>
   <br>
   EMail:&nbsp;<input name="email_address" size="25" type="email" value="Parul@Gynapsys.com"><br><br>
   Phone:&nbsp;<input maxlength="3" name="area_code" size="3" type="tel" value="650">
   &nbsp;<input maxlength="7" name="number" size="7" type="tel" value="3301096">
</form>
<br>
Select Order Type:&nbsp; 
<select id="deliverytype" onchange="deliverytype(this)">
   <option value="pickup" selected>
      Pickup
   </option>
   <option value="delivery">
      Delivery
   </option>
</select>
<br>
<p></p>
<div id="deliverydetails" style="display:none;">
   <h3>Delivery Information</h3>
   <form id="deliveryinfo" name="deliveryinfo" style="font-size:14px">
      Delivery Contact Phone:&nbsp;
      <input maxlength="3" name="darea_code" size="3" type="tel" value="650">
      &nbsp;
      <input maxlength="7" name="dnumber" size="7" type="tel" value="3301096"><br><br>
      Delivery Address:<br><br>
      Street Number:&nbsp;
      <input maxlength="5" name="street_number" size="5" type="text" value="123">
      &nbsp;Street:&nbsp;
      <input name="street" size="20" type="text" value="Speedline Street"><br><br>
      City:&nbsp;
      <select id="city" name="city" onchange="" onfocus="">
         <option selected value="San Carlos">
            San Carlos
         </option>
         <option value="Mukilteo">
            Mukilteo
         </option>
         <option value="Los Angeles">
            Los Angeles
         </option>
      </select>
      &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Province:&nbsp;
      <select id="province_state" name="province_state" onchange="" onfocus="">
         <option selected value="CA">
            CA
         </option>
         <option value="WA">
            WA
         </option>
         <option value="NY">
            NY
         </option>
      </select>
      &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Zip:&nbsp;
      <select id="postal_zip" name="postal_zip" onchange="" onfocus="">
         <option selected value="94070">
            94070
         </option>
         <option value="90208">
            90208
         </option>
         <option value="94011">
            94011
         </option>
      </select>
      <br><br>
      Delivery Inst:&nbsp;
      <input name="delivery_instructions" size="40" type="text" value="Use front door and ring the bell on right">
   </form>
</div>
<!--End of deliverydetails--><br><br>
<div>
```

Comment: onclick will fire only when you click on it. You want the onchange event

Comment: onChange doesn't show up with a div in dreamweaver. Let me try it

Comment: `onclick` is simply working when you click on it. you can use `onchange` or `onselect`, which also works as their name - `onchange` works when you change something and `onselect` works when you select something.

Comment: @Ritwick why are you using Dreamweaver?

Comment: @Fallenreaper I am new to HTML and Javascript. Do you have a suggestion for a better software for HTML and Javascript coding?

Comment: @Ritwick 1) sublime text 3 2) notepad++

Comment: @JuanMendes onChange works :)

Comment: @Ritwick I use NotePad++, VIM, and sometimes Visual Studios 2013 (because they made some pretty solid strides in WebDev tools)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Listen for the [change event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/change). In the latest browsers, it bubbles up to the div.

```
document.getElementById('customer').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    e = e || window.event
    alert('changed ' + e.target.id + ' to ' + e.target.value);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/LaZgr/1/

If you need to support IE 8 and below, you can set listeners on all the fields yourself or see [Does the onchange event propagate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265074/does-the-onchange-event-propagate)

One of the answers there [explains how to use jQuery to workaround it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4722246/227299)

```
// In jQuery 1.4+ the change event bubbles in all browsers, including IE.    
$('div.field_container').change(function() {
   // code here runs in all browers, including IE.
});
```