# VueJS event binding in v-for

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm displaying a list of objects with VueJS like so:

```
<div v-for="register in registers">
    <input type="checkbox" v-model="register.isEnabled">
    <input type="text" v-model="register.name" :disabled="!register.isEnabled">

    <span v-if="register.saved">Saved</span>
    <span v-else><a @click="save(register)">Save now</a></span>
</div>
```

What I'd like to do, is to watch for changes in this object's values and set the `saved` attribute to `false`. This is an exemplary version of my Vue instance:

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        registers: [
            { isEnabled: true, name: 'Register 1', saved: true },
            { isEnabled: false, name: '', saved: true },
        ]
    },
    methods: {
        save: function(event) {
            // Save object, set saved to true
        }
    }
});
```

I've tried settings an onchange listener to the div with the `v-for` attribute:

```
<div v-for="register in registers" @change="onChange(register)">
```

However this only triggers when the first input element is changed (e.g. the checkbox).

Am I able to somehow listen to all changes made to this register object, without having to add a `@change` event to every single input? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I able to somehow listen to all changes made to this register object, without having to add a @change event to every single input?

This sounds like a pretty reasonable solution actually, especially since [the change event doesn't bubble](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265074/does-the-onchange-event-propagate).

I tried to come up with a solution using [watch](https://vuejs.org/api/#watch), [but since deep watch is not an option for large arrays](https://github.com/vuejs/Discussion/issues/336), it would become pretty messy.

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    ready: function() {
        this.registers.forEach(function(register, index) {
            this.$watch('registers[' + index + ']', function(newRegister, oldRegister) {
              // Check that it wasn't the `saved` state that changed
              if (newRegister.saved === oldRegister.saved) {
                  newRegister.saved = false;
              }
            });
        });
    },
    data: {
        registers: [
            { isEnabled: true, name: 'Register 1', saved: true },
            { isEnabled: false, name: '', saved: true },
        ]
    },
    methods: {
        save: function(event) {
            // Save object, set saved to true
        }
    }
});
```

And then you would have to rebind all the watchers in case the registers properties change.

So you're probably easier off just using `@change` listeners.

Comment: Agree with nils generally ... run a loop on the properties of each item you want to watch in the array ... although nils I think it's this.$watch to setup the listener, not this.watch ;)

Comment: Thanks, corrected that ;) I'm not voting for my solution though, I'm much for the OP's solution :)