# Selenium onChange not working

Tags: events, selenium, onchange

I have tried a number of things to try and get Selenium to pick up an 'onchange' event from a drop down menu, none of which has worked.

The offending HTML is:

```
<select onchange="doOpperation(this.options[this.selectedIndex]); this.selectedIndex = 0;" name="opps_ondemand" id="opps_ondemand">
  <option value="none" id="ondemand">Mark as...</option>
  <option cmd="blah1" value="add">Something</option>
  <option cmd="blah2" value="remove">None</option>
</select>
```

I have read that Selenium IDE doesn't record some on* events, and so it would be wise to use fireEvent():

```
$this->click("opps_ondemand");
$this->select("opps_ondemand", "label=Mark as...");
$this->click("//option[@value='add']");
sleep(3);
$this->fireEvent("//select[@id='opps_ondemand']", "change");
```

However, this does not work (with or without the fireEvent).  I have also tried using

```
$this->fireEvent("locator", "click");
```

instead of

```
$this->click("locator");
```

but this did nothing.

Selenium does not complain about these locators not existing so I am assuming it can see the select/option elements fine.  The problem seems to be the onChange event.

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm testing on Firefox 3.5.8.

Answer (score 5):

I encountered exactly this problem, but in IE only (Firefox and Google Chrome works fine for me)

I found the solution to be manually forcing the update using JavaScript through Selenium's `runScript`. Some ways to do that can be found here:

[How do I programmatically force an onchange event on an input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136617/how-do-i-programatically-force-an-onchange-event-on-an-input)

For example, if I have jQuery in my Web page, I would do this:

```
$this->select('IDOfSelectElement', '*some label*');
$this->runScript("$('#IDOfSelectElement').trigger('change')");
```

Answer (score 2):

tried this?

```
$this->fireEvent("opps_ondemand", "onchange");
```

fireEvent(element_id, event_to_trigger);