# jQuery change select list selectedIndex on hover event and also send click?

Tags: jquery

I have an image on my page that when hovered changes the selectedIndex of a select list.

```
// change the selected index of the select list on element hover
$("#mySelectList").attr('selectedIndex', 1); // works
```

The select list also fires another function on change.  This works when I manually change the options from the select list but not when I change the selectedIndex on the hover event (code above).

My question, is there a way that I can also send a "click" event or something similar?  Basically I want to be able to change the selectedIndex of the select list and also have it fire the other function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can try is to trigger the change (or click or whetever) event.

```
$('#mySelectList').trigger('change');
```

or

```
$('#mySelectList').trigger('click');
```

after you've set the selected index

Comment: Thanks!  $('#mySelectList').trigger('change'); worked.  'click' did not work for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

You can fire the `onchange` event of the `select` control:

[How do I programmatically force an onchange event on an input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136617/how-do-i-programatically-force-an-onchange-event-on-an-input)

Just use:

```
$("#mySelectList").onchange()
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not refactor the function that you would perform normally in the click event into a JavaScript function and then call it directly?

Comment: hi rcravens - i needed it to call the function from the select list since the select list passes values to the function.  i'm sure there is a way to surpass going through the select list though and invoking the function directly from he hover / click event on the original element.  Just haven't figured that out. but trigger('change') works for now.