# onChanged event not fired from input field in iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, dom-events, onchange

I have a form that tracks its dirty state by listening to the `onChange` events of all its form fields. If the form is dirty, the user is warned about unsaved changes when he tries to leave the page or tries to select another item.

This works well with the form in a "normal page".

This form is also used inside an iframe. When changing the value of the first input field and then jumping to another field in the form, the `onChange` event is triggered as expected and the form is set dirty. But when only one input field is changed and you click anywhere outside the iframe, the `onChange` event of the changed input field is *not* triggered. It seems as if the input field does not really loses its focus, when the iframe loses it.

How can I make sure that the `onChange` event is fired when clicking outside the iframe?

Comment: Please can you provide your piece of code ?

Comment: Did you try to make a listener for click event int the iframe, and another on the input. In the input event callback, just call the  stopPropagation. So now you can detect click made on the input(the focus), and click makde outside (blur)

Comment: This was a timing issue. When clicking outside the iframe, the iframe gets updated by the outer frame and the "dirty form" inside the iframe dissapears without having enough time to raise the onchange event. When i put the call that updates the iframe in a setTimeout and only run it after 300ms, the form has enough time to trigger the onchange event and set the form dirty.

Is there any chance that I can determine when it is possible to update the iframe so that the form elements had enough time to trigger any onchange event?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I programmatically force an onchange event on an input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136617/how-do-i-programmatically-force-an-onchange-event-on-an-input)

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably have to check to see if the iframe's window.blur event triggered then check to see if the then use JS to trigger the onchange event

[How do I programmatically force an onchange event on an input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136617/how-do-i-programatically-force-an-onchange-event-on-an-input)