# Knockout observable value is undefined for input type=password if its value is set by browser auto fill mode

Tags: knockout.js

The password observable value is always undefined if the input field of type="password" gets filled by auto-fill-mode of the browser. I only enter the first character in the username field and select the name from the dropdown list. The password field gets filled by the browser.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var viewModel = function () {
                var self = this;
                self.UserName = ko.observable();
                self.Password = ko.observable();
                self.Submit = function () {
                    var un = self.UserName();
                    var pw = self.Password(); // Password value is undefined!!!!
                    alert(pw);
                };
            };

            ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
        });
    </script>


<form id="LoginForm" data-bind="submit: Submit">
<fieldset>
    <label for="UserName">Username</label>
    <input id="UserName" data-bind="value: UserName" name="UserName" type="text" />

    <label for="Password">Password</label>
    <input id="Password" data-bind="value: Password" type="password" />
    <button type="submit">Login</button>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Sorry, the question was "Why is the value not updated by knockout?".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the behavior your model is displaying is because the Knockout model updates during onChange events, and the input does not receive an onChange event when it is auto-filled. The only workaround to this that I could come up with was manually triggering an onChange event when you submit.

```
self.Submit = function () {
    var un = self.UserName();
    $("#Password").trigger("change");
    var pw = self.Password(); // Password value is no longer undefined!!!!
    alert(pw);
};
```

This solution (tested and works), which I got from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136617/how-do-i-programatically-force-an-onchange-event-on-an-input), relies on jQuery. If you don't want a jQuery solution, the linked question provides a few other solutions as well.