# how to use javascript to auto fill cascade select?

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a program to auto fill form blanks in the web pages. With javascript I can deal with normal blanks like username input and passwd input. But when it comes to cascade select, like some web pages asking you to input your address info, there's 3 selects: choose country, choose province and choose city. The content of the second menu is loaded upon the onchange event of the first one, so as to the third select.

I'm wondering how to auto fill these 3 selects, given that I've already known the value for each one of them. Could any one help?

The following code seems not working:

```
 document.getElementById("selProvinces").value='11';
 document.getElementById("selProvinces").onchange(); 
 document.getElementById("selCities").value='113';
 document.getElementById("selCities").onchange(); 
 document.getElementById("selDistricts").value='1190';
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have a few problems here.

1. In some browsers, calling `.onchange()` won't actually trigger the event. See this answer to [How do I programatically force an onchange event on an input?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/136810/11569) for more details.
2. If the page you're filling in is ajaxing in the next lot of values in the cascade, 'selCities' might not contain the value 113 just yet. You could set a timeout and poll periodically to see if 'selCities' has some values in it before setting the value
3. It might not actually be the onchange event that they're using for the cascading. The oldschool way used to be onclick. They might be doing it onblur. Possibly silly, but worth peeking at the source to make sure :)