# how to trigger onChange event on text input when the value is changed programmatically - react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events

```
render() {
    return (
        <input
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            value={this.props.transcript}
            type='text
        />
    )    
}
```

in the above example, If text value is changed using keyboard inputs, it will trigger onChange event, but if it's being changed dynamically via this.props.transcript, onChange event is not triggered. How to solve this issue?

Comment: Why would you need on change on that? it seems unnecessary requirement.

Comment: because I want to trigger the onChange event both for keyboard input changes and as well as when the this,props.transcript changes @Justcode

Comment: This might help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136617/how-do-i-programmatically-force-an-onchange-event-on-an-input

Comment: Look in to the `componentDidUpdate` method (https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) - which gives you access to the previous props so you can compare the `props.transcript` value to see if it's changed, and call `this.handleChange` if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use componentWillReceiveProps hooks to achieve it, as your props get updated it will call componentWillReceiveProps method. Inside the method it is your playground. Please make sure this method will be called on each and every time the props changes

```
import React,{ Component } from 'react'

class InputBox extends Component {
    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
        // write your logic here or call to the common method
        console.log(nextProps.transcript);
    }
    handleChange(e){
        console.log(e.target.value)
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <section>
                <input
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                    value={this.props.transcript}
                    type='text'
                />
            </section>
        );
    }
}

export default InputBox;
```

Answer (score 0):

If we are using react setState correctly it should work without issue but, Look like you have two sets of values one coming from parent  "this.props.transcript" and one in input box which is handled by "this.handleChange". Alternately, check need of react hooks like "componentWillUpdate" and "componentWillReceiveProps" to apply state change on input.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing more of the code, it looks like your value for transcript in the input is wrong.

Try value={props.transcript} and if that doesn’t work value={this.state.transcript}.