# Fill password field programatically like real user

Tags: javascript

I have input field like below

```
<input type="password" placeholder="Password" autocorrect="off" maxlength="30" autofocus="autofocus" animate="true" label="" rules="[object Object]">
```

and button like below

```
<button type="submit" class="button-orange wide">Login <!----></button>
```

So i am filling password with pure javascript like below

```
document.querySelectorAll('input[type=password]')[0].value = "12345";
document.querySelectorAll('.button-orange')[0].click();
```

Problem is the actual website is tracking keydown or something , its always alerting me password is empty also when i focus on input password tab , Password filled getting empty.

How do i fill password like real human typed it.

Comment: [How do I programmatically force an onchange event on an input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136617/how-do-i-programmatically-force-an-onchange-event-on-an-input/136810) - this might help

Comment: try to trigger keyevents https://stackoverflow.com/questions/961532/firing-a-keyboard-event-in-javascript

Comment: I tried both , its still making my inputfield empty on focus

Answer (score 0):

May be you have to set redOnly property of the field to true after filling it with value by JavaScript

```
document.querySelectorAll('input[type=password]')[0].value = "12345";
document.querySelectorAll('input[type=password]')[0].readOnly = true;
```

Comment: Still same , you can try it out at https://kite.zerodha.com/

Comment: So what if you set a function that return false to focus event of the field

Comment: Still when i press login button , its emptying