# How to execute change event on select when option change?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

How can I execute the onchange event handler on select when I change the option?

```js
document.getElementById('selct').value=2;
```

```html
<select id="selct" onchange="alert('change success')">
  <option value="0">val1</option>
  <option value="1">val2</option>
  <option value="2">val3</option>
  <option value="3">val4</option>
  <option value="4">val5</option>
  <option value="5">val6</option>
</select>
```

When I do that, the result is `val3`, but select's `onchange` didn't work.
How can I fix it?

Comment: Missing `e` in `getElmentById`

Comment: The event is only triggered when the user changes it, not when you change it from JavaScript.

Comment: there is no other way ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I programmatically force an onchange event on an input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136617/how-do-i-programmatically-force-an-onchange-event-on-an-input)

Answer (score 1):

Changing `value` programmatically using Javascript doesn't fire [`change`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change) event. To make it work you have to fire the event programmatically.

```
var sel = document.getElementById('selct');
sel.value=2;
sel.onchange();
```

```js
var sel = document.getElementById('selct');
sel.value = 2;
sel.onchange();
```

```html
<select id="selct" onchange="alert('change success')">
  <option value="0">val1</option>
  <option value="1">val2</option>
  <option value="2">val3</option>
  <option value="3">val4</option>
  <option value="4">val5</option>
  <option value="5">val6</option>
</select>
```

From [MDN docs, change events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change#Description) for `select` tag fires when:

> When the user commits the change explicitly (e.g. by selecting a value from a 's dropdown with a mouse click, by selecting a date from a date picker for , by selecting a file in the file picker for , etc.);

Refer :  [How can I trigger an onchange event manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856513/how-can-i-trigger-an-onchange-event-manually)

Comment: i already try it but did not work
i got this eroor ====document.getElementById(...).onchange is not a function

Comment: get the same eroor sel.onchange is not a function :(

Comment: @danial check console.log(sel)

Answer (score 0):

This work for me:

```
document.getElementById('selct').dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
```