# Javascript click on option does not drop it down - Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome-extension, drop-down-menu, click

I am making an Automated chrome extension.
I need to select an option in a dropdown.
I used

```
var element = document.getElementByClassName("className");
element.value = 1;
```

This changes the value on the screen, but doesn't trigger the web app, since it is triggered by mouse click.
So I tried clicking on the option menu, but the option does not drop down when I click with

```
element.click()
```

or when I click the parent of this class, it doesn't drop down.
I tried clicking by position

```
let ele = document.elementsFromPoint(1,1)
for(let i=0;i<ele.length;i++){
    ele.click();
}
```

But again this doesn't work too.

The html of the dropdown is:

```
<div class="css-1dbjc4n r-bnwqim">
  <select
    aria-label="Ay"
    data-focusable="true"
    class="r-30o5oe r-1niwhzg r-17gur6a r-1yadl64 r-jwli3a r-1loqt21 r-ubezar r-crgep1 r-1ny4l3l r-t60dpp r-iphfwy r-n072k1 r-vmopo1 r-c2syf2"
  >
    <option value="" aria-disabled="true" disabled="" class="r-yfoy6g"></option>
    <option value="1" class="r-yfoy6g">Ocak</option>
    <option value="2" class="r-yfoy6g">Şubat</option>
    <option value="3" class="r-yfoy6g">Mart</option>
    <option value="4" class="r-yfoy6g">Nisan</option>
    <option value="5" class="r-yfoy6g">Mayıs</option>
    <option value="6" class="r-yfoy6g">Haziran</option>
    <option value="7" class="r-yfoy6g">Temmuz</option>
    <option value="8" class="r-yfoy6g">Ağustos</option>
    <option value="9" class="r-yfoy6g">Eylül</option>
    <option value="10" class="r-yfoy6g">Ekim</option>
    <option value="11" class="r-yfoy6g">Kasım</option>
    <option value="12" class="r-yfoy6g">Aralık</option></select
  ><svg
    viewBox="0 0 24 24"
    class="r-111h2gw r-4qtqp9 r-yyyyoo r-50lct3 r-fdch1b r-dnmrzs r-633pao r-u8s1d r-zchlnj r-1plcrui r-1v2oles r-lrvibr"
  >
    <g>
      <path
        d="M20.207 8.147c-.39-.39-1.023-.39-1.414 0L12 14.94 5.207 8.147c-.39-.39-1.023-.39-1.414 0-.39.39-.39 1.023 0 1.414l7.5 7.5c.195.196.45.294.707.294s.512-.098.707-.293l7.5-7.5c.39-.39.39-1.022 0-1.413z"
      ></path>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Is there a way to simulate mouse click on a dropdown-option menu?
I don't want to use Selenium or AHK since I have been developing this extension for a long time.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you share what the html of the dropdown looks like?

Comment: getElements not Element

Comment: @Dominik I added

Comment: @EugenSunic It doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to change the state of the select input you can use the following

Choose whichever element you want by changing the index

```
 const index = 2;
 document.getElementsByTagName("select")[0].options[index].selected = true
```

Comment: This changes the dropdown but does not trigger the web app. When an option is selected it changes something in the page; but by your way, it is not triggered. The page stays the same

Comment: Send a `change` event additionally, [How do I programmatically force an onchange event on an input?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36648958)